# JavaScript-uploading Image on Amazon s3 after decoding it from base 64

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-s3, base64

I am trying to upload an image on amazon s3 after decoding it from base64 like this:

```
var data = url.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/,"");
                        var decodedData = window.atob(data);

                        var params = {
                            Key : 'phonegap/' + i,
                            Body : decodedData,
                            ContentType : 'image/jpeg',
                            ACL : 'public-read',
                            StorageClass : 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
                        };

                        bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                            //some code
                        });
```

the code is working fine and the image is uploaded on s3 in the required bucket .But what I feel is that the image gets corrupted in between this processing of image. However I checked the Base64 string and it looks fine as I uploaded the base64 string on http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/ and it gave me the same image. Also, again I encoded the the decodedData like this:

```
var encodedData=window.btoa(decodedData);
```

and I used this encoded base64 string and it was exactly the same as it should have been as I checked it again on askapache converter. But still the image that is getting uploaded on s3 seems corrupt to me as I cannot view it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what exactly the issue was. The thing was I am using phonegap api which generated the base64 code using ISO-8859-1 charset and when I used the atob() method to decode it, By default, it used utf-8 charset so during this process the image got corrupted as both the charset were different so I followed this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding and used this code from these methods from there:

```
function base64DecToArr (sBase64, nBlocksSize) {

  var
    sB64Enc = sBase64.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/]/g, ""), nInLen = sB64Enc.length,
    nOutLen = nBlocksSize ? Math.ceil((nInLen * 3 + 1 >> 2) / nBlocksSize) * nBlocksSize : nInLen * 3 + 1 >> 2, taBytes = new Uint8Array(nOutLen);

  for (var nMod3, nMod4, nUint24 = 0, nOutIdx = 0, nInIdx = 0; nInIdx < nInLen; nInIdx++) {
    nMod4 = nInIdx & 3;
    nUint24 |= b64ToUint6(sB64Enc.charCodeAt(nInIdx)) << 18 - 6 * nMod4;
    if (nMod4 === 3 || nInLen - nInIdx === 1) {
      for (nMod3 = 0; nMod3 < 3 && nOutIdx < nOutLen; nMod3++, nOutIdx++) {
        taBytes[nOutIdx] = nUint24 >>> (16 >>> nMod3 & 24) & 255;
      }
      nUint24 = 0;

    }
  }

  return taBytes;
}


function b64ToUint6 (nChr) {

  return nChr > 64 && nChr < 91 ?
      nChr - 65
    : nChr > 96 && nChr < 123 ?
      nChr - 71
    : nChr > 47 && nChr < 58 ?
      nChr + 4
    : nChr === 43 ?
      62
    : nChr === 47 ?
      63
    :
      0;

}
```

and called `base64DecToArr(data,'1')` in the `params` variable for the Body attribute like this:

```
var params = {
                            Key : 'phonegap/' + i,
                            Body : base64DecToArr(data,'1'),
                            ContentType : 'image/jpeg',
                            ACL : 'public-read',
                            StorageClass : 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
                        };
```

and removed the atob() method to decode the `data`. Hope this helps someone.